# Staged git lfs files not being intercepted by git-lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am trying to commit/push a 1.2gb tar file to git lfs server using Git on Windows 10

I have tracked the tar extension with:

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git lfs track '*.tar'
```

Running `git lfs track` returns

```
Listing tracked patterns
    Folder\'*.tar' (Folder\.gitattributes)
```

I add the .gitattributes file

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git add .gitattributes
```

I add the large file

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git add file.tar
```

Then confirm the file is being tracked with

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git lfs status

    On branch MyAwesomeBranch
    Git LFS objects to be pushed to origin/MyAwesomeBranch:


    Git LFS objects to be committed:

            .gitattributes  (Git: 136g1ea)
            file.tar (Git: 567d1ed)

    Git LFS objects not staged for commit:
```

I commit the file

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git commit -m "foo"
    [MyAwesomeBranch ecf9735] foo
     2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
     create mode 100644 Folder/.gitattributes
     create mode 100644 Folder/file.tar
```

And check that the file is being tracked

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git lfs track ls-files
```

Which returns nothing.

I check lfs status again and it isn't listed as an object to be pushed.

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git lfs status
On branch MyAwesomeBranch
Git LFS objects to be pushed to origin/MyAwesomeBranch:


Git LFS objects to be committed:


Git LFS objects not staged for commit:
```

As expected, pushing fails with

```
remote: error: File Folder/file.tar is 1229.43 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

What am i doing wrong? Why is the staged file not being committed to git lfs?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was resolved. 
This command was the issue:

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git lfs track '*.tar'
```

I should have used double quotes as below:

```
C:\FilepathTo\Folder> git lfs track "*.tar"
```

Which resolved my issue.

Comment: Alas.... This didn't work for me... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130913/why-cant-i-get-git-lfs-to-track-a-file