# Why can't I get git lfs to track a file

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm trying to use git lfs to track a large file, but cannot seem to add it to the repo as an lfs tracked file. The procedure I use is:

```
$ git lfs track "DeepMask.pth.tar"
Tracking "DeepMask.pth.tar"
$ git add .gitattributes
```

`.gitattributes` appears to have recognized the file I want git to track as an lfs file:

```
$ cat .gitattributes 
DeepMask.pth.tar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

So at this point, I think all is well. However, when I try to add the file to my repo as follows:

```
$ git add DeepMask.pth.tar
```

The file does not seem to be added as an lfs file:

```
$ git lfs status
On branch documentBranch
Objects to be pushed to origin/documentBranch:


Objects to be committed:

    .gitattributes (Git: e33cf7c)
    DeepMask.pth.tar (Git: 08f4391)

Objects not staged for commit:

$ git lfs ls-files
$
```

What am I doing wrong here? I saw the same problem with a solution at [Staged git lfs files not being intercepted by git-lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931154/staged-git-lfs-files-not-being-intercepted-by-git-lfs), but the solution there was to use double-quotes  in the `git lfs track` statement. I am already doing that. Although, unlike the person who posted that question, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

I've tried replacing `git lfs track "DeepMask.pth.tar"` with `git lfs track "*.tar", and even replacing the double-quotes with single quotes, in case I had the reverse of the problem found in [Staged git lfs files not being intercepted by git-lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931154/staged-git-lfs-files-not-being-intercepted-by-git-lfs), but to no avail.

==================================================================

I tried a simpler case, just creating a fresh git repository and seeing if I could add my large file to it.

```
$ mkdir tmpGit
$ cd tmpGit

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/Projects/tmpGit/.git/

$ ls
DeepMask.pth.tar <Note: I copied this file to my new directory using Nautilus>

$ git lfs track "*.tar"
Tracking "*.tar"

$ cat .gitattributes 
*.tar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

$ git add DeepMask.pth.tar 
$ git add .gitattributes 

$ git lfs status

Objects to be committed:

    .gitattributes (Git: 116c15b)
    DeepMask.pth.tar (Git: 08f4391)

Objects not staged for commit:


$ git lfs ls-files
$
```

Just to see exactly what files are in this directory and how large they are:

```
$ ls -alh
total 133M
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4.0K Sep 10 09:02 .
drwxrwxr-x 47 me me 4.0K Sep 10 09:01 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 133M Aug 19 22:24 DeepMask.pth.tar
drwxrwxr-x  8 me me 4.0K Sep 10 09:03 .git
-rw-rw----  1 me me   42 Sep 10 09:02 .gitattributes
```

Note: I obtain the same result when I create a small text file with the single word "Hello", and try to store it using git-lfs

Comment: Have you run `git lfs install` at least once on this computer?

Comment: I thought I had. But, apparently not. Now, I'm wondering why all the lfs commands were recognized?

Comment: *Now, I'm wondering why all the lfs commands were recognized?* You either had a leftover partial previous install, or a re-installation of Git overwrote some important configuration that Git-LFS installed in some system location.

Comment: Could it be connected to my use of multiple conda envs? I would've thought if I had installed in a different env, things would've failed to work entirely. But, maybe not?

Comment: `git lfs install` doesn't control whether Git LFS commands work.  It controls whether it gets invoked by Git, so when you run `git add` your files get processed through Git LFS.